# Multiple runs through GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to launch a GUI to my agent-based model (Repast) so that being able to run the model for many times. I am going to produce input parameters based on different distributions for different runs from GUI. Usually we should use batch file for different runs. However, I want to use GUI for this reason because I have GUI that can take care for one run but not for many runs. Could you help me with your idea in this respect?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of Repast Simphony has a GUI button which will let you run a batch of different parameter combinations from the GUI.

Make sure you are on a recent version of Repast Simphony (I use 2.1).  In the GUI there is a button at the top of the screen which looks like a lightning flash (between the restart simulation button and the Run VisAD button).  Click this - it lets you enter parameter combinations (on the "Batch parameters" tab) and run them locally (press the green arrow button to go).

Be aware that the displays will not be shown for each run - you will get any textual output collected, but not visualisations. Full instructions on how to configure parameter combinations are described [in this document](http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/RepastBatchRunsGettingStarted.pdf).

Behind the scenes, this GUI creates a batch file and runs jobs based on that.